# MySQL 5.6 Innodb running out single-table tablespace id's

Tags: mysql, percona

I am looking for general information regarding this message:

InnoDB: Warning: you are running out of new single-table tablespace id's.
InnoDB: Current counter is 2152000000 and it must not exceed 4294967280!
InnoDB: To reset the counter to zero you have to dump all your tables and
InnoDB: recreate the whole InnoDB installation.

Which counter? How do you query it? Does an entire restore fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

From Percona Support:

> When you create one table in innodb, that counter will be increased by 1.
>   This table id seems to be a 32bit value.

In my case, we created lots of temporary tables. On MySQL 5.6 default engine for temporary tables is innodb hence the problem. Once I changed it to MYISAM the warnings disappeared.